# Working out an exponentially increasing value without a function

Tags: exponential-function

This may seem very basic, but I am stumped by this. I have been set this by my Math tutor and I have no idea what to do. I have checked everywhere, but I am pretty sure my tutor made these set of questions himself, so I havn't found anything.

Here's what I have:

\begin{array}{rccc}
t: &  0 &  10 &  20 \\
X: & 275 & 440  & x 
\end{array}

The quantity $X$ is increasing exponentially with respect to time $t$. The table above shows values of $X$ for different values of $t$. Find $X$ when $t = 20$.

I think it would help me more if someone steered me in the right direction rather than just answering the question. I understand the basics of Natural Logs and exponentials so I am not completely blind on the subject. And I can work something like this out if I had the function connecting them, but I dont get how I can work out the relationship. But any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

-Arch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint*: You know that $X = Ca^t$ for some numbers $C$ and $a$ (this is what exponentially increasing means). Plug in $t=0$ and $t=10$ to give you two equations that can be used to solve for $C$ and $a$.

Comment: Ok, I got $C = 275$ and $a = 1.048$, so $Ca^20$ would equal around $702$, is that correct?

Comment: 704 to be exact.

Comment: Where did I got wrong then?

Comment: Oh nvm I see its just because I didn't use my calculator value. Thanks! :D

Comment: You probably rounded. A friendly reminder from Matt the Pure Mathematician, "Do not be tempted to round"

Comment: Now that you've done it with a calculator and logarithms, convince yourself that $$x = 440 \cdot \frac{440}{275}$$